# SQLite error - Failed to do file read

Tags: android-sdk, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Создаю локальную BD на андройде (SQLite), в базе порядка 15 таблиц.
При создании первых 9-ти, все идет без ошибок, но начиная с 10-й таблицы - в логах появляются следующие строки:

```
 E/SQLiteLog: (10) Failed to do file read, got: 0, amt: 4096, last Errno: 2
```

Ошибка вылетает более 10 раз на последние 5 таблиц. Само приложение не вылетает и нормально устанавливается на устройство. Далее сама БД в связке приложением работают нормально - как будто не было никаких ошибок. Наличие данной ошибки меня беспокоит, непонятно когда и где оно аукнется. Сам не разберусь что это за ошибка и откуда берется.

Comment: Скорее всего (точно не скажу) это некритичная ошибка, или ошибка с которой SQLite успешно справляется и работает дальше. Я бы не беспокоился.

Comment: Добавил  "NOT NULL" для "primary key" и "foreign key" - потестил вроде как ошибка пропала, вероятно в моем случае все было в отсутствии not null.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

Исправил создание таблиц в базе данных SQLite, для полей которые указаны в таблице как "primary key" или "foreign key" добавил инструкции "NOT NULL".

пример для наглядности:

```
db.execSQL(
            "create table "+ TBL_myOBJECT +" ("+
                    "_id integer NOT NULL,"+
                    "Name_obj text, "+

                    "primary key (_id) "+
                    ")"
    );

    db.execSQL(
            "create table "+ TBL_TYPE_FILE +" ("+
                    "_id integer NOT NULL,"+
                    "Name_type text, "+

                    "primary key (_id) "+
                    ")"
    );

    db.execSQL(
            "create table "+ TBL_OBJ_FILE +" ("+
                    "_id integer NOT NULL,"+
                    "Size_file integer, "+
                    "Date_create integer, "+
                    "Name_file text, "+
                    "Object_id integer NOT NULL, "+
                    "TypeFile_id integer NOT NULL, "+

                    "primary key (_id), "+
                    "foreign key (Object_id) references "+TBL_myOBJECT+" (_id),"+
                    "foreign key (TypeFile_id) references "+TBL_TYPE_FILE+" (_id)"+
                    ")"
    );
```